# Distribution of Y-X given a density function and independency

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Joint probability distribution  is given by $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-y}  & \text{if  } {0\leq x \leq y\leq \infty} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

I have to calculate the density functions for $Y-X$, $X/Y$ and also tell if $X,Y,Y-X,X/Y$ are independent to each other but I don't know where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

You know $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= e^{-y}~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant y\lt \infty}$

Then does this look familiar? $$\begin{align}f_{X,Y-X}(x,z) ~&=~ \left\lVert\dfrac{\partial(x, x+z)}{\partial (x, z)}\right\rVert \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,x+z) \\[1ex] &=~ f_{X,Y}(x,x+z) \end{align}$$

Also $$\begin{align}f_{X/Y,Y}(w,y) ~&=~ \left\lVert\dfrac{\partial(yw, y)}{\partial (w, y)}\right\rVert \cdot f_{X,Y}(yw, y)\\[1ex]&=~ \lvert y\rvert\cdot f_{X,Y}(yw,y)\end{align}$$

Now, can you use these joint distributions to evaluate the required marginal distributions, $f_{Y-X}(z), f_{X/Y}(w)~$ ?  (Remember too to identify their supports.)

---

NB: $\left\lVert\dfrac{\partial(yw, y)}{\partial (w, y)}\right\rVert$ is the magnitude of the Jacobian determinant: $$\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial yw}{\partial w} & \dfrac{\partial yw}{\partial y}\\[1ex]\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial w}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial y}\end{Vmatrix}~=~\begin{Vmatrix}y & w\\[1ex]0&1\end{Vmatrix} = \lvert y\rvert$$

And similarly the other.